# CSS postion not working in Chrome on Samsung

Tags: css, reactjs, google-chrome, sass, css-position

```
nav#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5rem;
  background: white;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $light-grey;
}
```

Fixed does not work on mobile. I tried `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden`, but nothing changed. What can I do? I'm using reactjs.

```
<nav id="navbar">
  <Logo/>
    <div className="is-pull-right desktop-menu">
      {menuItems} {/*array map*/}
      {adminBtn} {/*array map*/}
    </div>
  <Dropdown/> {/*component for bulma dropdown*/}
</nav>
```

Comment: What browser and what mobile operating system

Comment: @minimin_bamm share your `html` code also for better understanding. And also define browser and mobile.

Comment: Can you share your html  code

Comment: @Ijaz Ali 

Added! 
and I use chrome, mobile is samsung internet

Comment: @AlanM Added! I'm using reactjs

Comment: @Alan M macOS Catalina and android 8

Comment: @minimin_bamm sorry i am working with react-js. If you share proper html then i can  guide you with this.

Comment: @IjazAli All I use in my Navbar is the shared code. Do you need anything else?

Comment: @minimin_bamm you have used component so, please add html at the place of component.Or you can implement this code on sandbox and share of sandbox with me.